# Make smaller canvas match parent

Tags: android

I have a square canvas that is 640x640 px. I would like this canvas to match its parent which is 720x720 px. I've tried scaling it but the size of the square remains the same but the content is scaled instead. This is what I'm doing.

```
    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(640, 640, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    mCanvas.scale(1.125f, 1.125f);
```

In the layout xml the canvas is set to match parent and also its parent.

```
<view class="com.example.classes.SquareLayout"
    android:id="@+id/image_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="#999999">

    <view class="com.example.classes.PhotoCanvas"
        android:id="@+id/photo_canvas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

</view>
```

(The 300dp for its parent is changed to whatever the width is in: SquareLayout.

PhotoCanvas:

```
public PhotoCanvas (Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(c, attrs);
    this.c = c;
    mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    cameraIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(c.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_take_photo);

    try {
        mCallback = (OnAreaClickedListener) c;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(c.toString() + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
    }
}


@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(640, 640, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    mCanvas.scale(1.125f, 1.125f);
    Log.i(Constants.TAG, "onSizeChanged");
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
    layoutDraw();

    Log.i(Constants.TAG, "onDraw");
}
```

What I want is to create a image later that is alway 640x640 px on all screen sizes, densities and resolution. 
Any suggestions?

EDIT: Added xml

Comment: `canvas` is not a `view`? Can you tell me how you defined it in the layout `XML` to `match_parent`?

Comment: post your code of canvas

Comment: Added code of canvas and xml.

Comment: android:layout_height="300dp" Its fixed height , then where did you change this

Comment: @Arju It doesn't matter if I change that value. If I put it to 500db it remains the same. http://s24.postimg.org/4xy7bx5j9/Screenshot_2013_11_22_12_59_59.png The grey area is the parent layout SquareLayout, the white square is the canvas.

Comment: try fill_parent instead of match , just a try

Comment: Make sure that parent of  class="com.example.classes.SquareLayout" view has more width

Comment: Fill_parent doesn't work. And the parent of squarelayout is the full width of the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realised I had the wrong approach. The size of the canvas doesn't matter. I will make it match each phone and then when its picture saving time I just scale that to desired size.